# Debian-compatible apps to open Microsoft Access file?

Tags: linux, debian, microsoft-access

What packages are good for opening a 500+ MB .accdb file?

I'm running Debian 9.3 on my computer.

Comment: Can LibreOffice open it? Apparently on Windows it should be able to, not sure about debian though

Comment: None.  You can read the data tables, but not open any native Access files.  Moving my databases to Linux was a pain, but now it's done.  LibreOffice base is similar to Access.  Depends on what you want to do with it.  I actually moved my databases into MariaDB, then pointed Libreoffice at them.  That was so that I could also still use then from Access too.  Simple fields work.  More advanced field types are not as easy.  Go to ask.libreoffice.org.